# How to count all files in filesystem quickly?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, filesystems

I need to count all files in my `*NIX` file system as a part of my project to accomplish this, created recursive method as follows:

```
// private member -> quint64 m_files_count = 0;
quint64 MyClass::filesToCount(const QString &searchDirs, const QStringList &excl_dirs = QStringList())
{
    QDir dir(searchDirs);
    if(excl_dirs.contains(dir.absolutePath()))
        return 0;
    QStringList dirs = dir.entryList(QDir::Dirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::Hidden | QDir::NoSymLinks);
    foreach(QString d, dirs)
    {
        filesToCount(dir.absoluteFilePath(d), excl_dirs);
    }
    QStringList files = dir.entryList(QDir::Files | QDir::Hidden | QDir::NoSymLinks);
    m_files_count += files.size();
    return m_files_count;
}
```

But this methods works very slowly and takes the time!
Can you suggest any fast way to count all files in the filesystem?

Kinds regards!

Comment: The *entire* filesystem? That's going to take some time.

Comment: The only problem with recursion is recursion. Anyway, the only way to significantly speed this up is by reading the file table. This is going to be specific to the file system in use.

Comment: Yes, but my GUI is freezing while waiting for result

Comment: @IInspectable How to do this? I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with ext4 filesystem.

Comment: I see, so you are trying to tackle a different problem altogether: Keep your UI responsive while performing a lengthy operation. You should have asked that question instead.

Comment: If GUI freezing is your problem, run this function in a different thread or try http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent.html#run